# Eclipse: save server responses and return them if server(data source) goes down

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there some eclipse plugin or some other non eclipse tool which can act as a proxy between my dev environment and my data sources to save all the responses coming in from the servers and return those saved responses to me in case the data source goes down?

edit: the goal here is not to just save the responses, but also to act as a data source for me for the time my data source goes down, so I can continue devloping

Comment: This is usually done by unit test. Write some test case that mock up a data source, for example, from a local file dataset.xml, and develop/debug/test the rest of your code against this mock data source.

Answer (score 0):

try logging API like log4j or slf4j in your program to log the communication between you and the server , that way you will have data saved till the communication breaks . e.g.

```
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("YOURLOG");
```

then

```
log.debug(<request-sent>);
log.debug(<response-received>);
```

Comment: I already have log4j, and use it the way you suggest. But this is not what I want, I want something that will act as my data source during the time my source server is down